# Edit points of FreeShape - reduce path

Tags: c#, .net, graphicspath

I'm having some GUI letting a user draw costimized GraphicsPath.
I've created it using the GraphicsPath AddLine function.

Now I want to implement what you can see in the attached Microsoft Word image - "Edit Points".

[image]

I'm facing several problems:

1. My path has hunders of "Lines"->each is only one pixel sized. I want to select only "key Points". How do I do that? It's kind of revers of "Flatten", couldn't find such a function.
2. Is there an existing .Net function to draw the small blue rectangles, and the small green circle around the path? and what about the rectangles around each selected point?
   [image]

Each help, even partial, would be appreciated.

Comment: No on both acoounts. 1) You can only try to reduce the number of points by looping over them, calculating the (accumulated) slope and mark all points for deletion until the slope has changed more than some epsilon.  . - [I never got around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553184/how-can-i-simplify-a-graphicspath) to wrintinf the simplyfy function.. - 2) As long as your path consists of lines only, the are no control points. You can examine the other points array in the path data, which hold the points types to check.

Comment: Thanks! do you know any existing way to reduce the number of points?

Comment: I have decided to write a quick one. You can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553184/how-can-i-simplify-a-graphicspath/50715073#50715073)

Comment: Thanks! made my day. :)

Comment: I have [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553184/how-can-i-simplify-a-graphicspath/50715073?noredirect=1#comment88574729_50715073) the function math..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of your question do have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553184/how-can-i-simplify-a-graphicspath), which has a reduction function for a `List<Point>`. Note that the `GraphicsPath.PathPoints`  collection is read-only, so you have to re-create the path from the reduced points list.

A few remarks on the second part:

- There is no built-in routine to create the handles. Nor to make them do anything. So you need to code for them.
- I append a simple class `MoveLabel` which can be used for this. It can be placed on a control or be added to its `Controls` collection. Then you can move it around. I have added a callback function `MoveAction`  to process the result when the mouse is released.

You can either add a ..

```
public delegate void Moved(MoveLabel sender);
```

..to the form class, or, to avoid the `Form1` reference, outside of the form class but in scope for the `MoveLabel`.

It can be used directly to move points in  points list:

Create it on a panel:

```
var lab= new MoveLabel(Color.CadetBlue, 9, Point.Round(points[i]), i);
lab.Parent = panel;
lab.MoveAction = moved;
```

A simple processing function:

```
void moved(MoveLabel sender)
{
    points[sender.PointIndex] = 
            new Point(sender.Left - sender.Width / 2, sender.Top - sender.Height / 2);
    panel.Invalidate();
}
```

Note that the `GraphicsPath.PathPoints` are read-only, so we have to re-create the path from the new points list! Actually one can modify individual `PathPoints` in code, but the result does not stick; so one has to copy the `PathPoints` to a `PointF[]`, modify them there and re-create the path. For complex paths best by using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142514(v=vs.110).aspx)..

If you want to implement a rotation (or other transformations) you can use the [GraphicsPath.Transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.transform(v=vs.110).aspx) function. You can use moveable labels to determine the rotation or scaling data..
Here is my minimal `MoveLabel` class:

```
public class MoveLabel : Label
{
    public Form1.Moved MoveAction { get; set; }
    public int PointIndex { get; set; }

    private Point mDown = Point.Empty;

    public MoveLabel()
    {
        MouseDown += (ss, ee) => { mDown = ee.Location; };
        MouseMove += (ss, ee) => {
            if (ee.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left))
            {
                Location = new Point(Left + ee.X - Width / 2, Top + ee.Y - Height / 2);
                mDown = Location;
            }
        };
        MouseUp += (ss, ee) => { if (MoveAction != null) MoveAction(this);  };
    }

    public MoveLabel(Color c, int size, Point location, int pointIndex) : this()
    {
        BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;
        Size = new Size(size, size);
        Location = location;
        PointIndex = pointIndex;
    }
}
```

This will also work fine to move points from bezier curves. By adding a call `MoveAction(this);` to the `MouseMove` linq code you can get live updates.. Make sure the `Panels` are [DoubleBuffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185298/update-datagridview-very-frequently/44188565?s=1%7C25.3177#44188565) for this :-)

Example:

[image]

---

Btw: I just came upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152729/gdi-c-how-to-save-an-image-as-emf/152830#152830) which shows how easily the curve or any other GDI+ vector drawing can be saved to `emf`, preserving the vector quality!

---

**Update:** Instead of a `Panel`, which is a `Container` control and not really meant to draw onto you can use a `Picturebox` or a `Label` (with `Autosize=false`); both have the `DoubleBuffered` property turned on out of the box and support drawing better than `Panels` do.

Comment: As always - your answers are complete, elaborated, and just "throw" me strait forward. too bad I can't tripple upvote..

Answer (score 1):

For the reduce points part - I ended up using Dougles-Packer algorithm, found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7982089/3225391
I cannot recall if I found this implementation somewhere. If someone knows where from it comes - I'll be happy to link his answer and give him the feedback.

my implementation is here:

```
    public static List<Point> DouglasPeuckerReduction
        (List<Point> Points, Double Tolerance)
    {
        if (Points == null || Points.Count < 3)
            return Points;

        Int32 firstPoint = 0;
        Int32 lastPoint = Points.Count - 1;
        List<Int32> pointIndexsToKeep = new List<Int32>();

        //Add the first and last index to the keepers
        pointIndexsToKeep.Add(firstPoint);
        pointIndexsToKeep.Add(lastPoint);

        //The first and the last point cannot be the same
        while (Points[firstPoint].Equals(Points[lastPoint]))
        {
            lastPoint--;
        }

        DouglasPeuckerReduction(Points, firstPoint, lastPoint,
        Tolerance, ref pointIndexsToKeep);

        List<Point> returnPoints = new List<Point>();
        pointIndexsToKeep.Sort();
        foreach (Int32 index in pointIndexsToKeep)
        {
            returnPoints.Add(Points[index]);
        }

        return returnPoints;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Douglases the peucker reduction.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="points">The points.</param>
    /// <param name="firstPoint">The first point.</param>
    /// <param name="lastPoint">The last point.</param>
    /// <param name="tolerance">The tolerance.</param>
    /// <param name="pointIndexsToKeep">The point index to keep.</param>
    private static void DouglasPeuckerReduction(List<Point>
        points, Int32 firstPoint, Int32 lastPoint, Double tolerance,
        ref List<Int32> pointIndexsToKeep)
    {
        Double maxDistance = 0;
        Int32 indexFarthest = 0;

        for (Int32 index = firstPoint; index < lastPoint; index++)
        {
            Double distance = PerpendicularDistance
                (points[firstPoint], points[lastPoint], points[index]);
            if (distance > maxDistance)
            {
                maxDistance = distance;
                indexFarthest = index;
            }
        }

        if (maxDistance > tolerance && indexFarthest != 0)
        {
            //Add the largest point that exceeds the tolerance
            pointIndexsToKeep.Add(indexFarthest);

            DouglasPeuckerReduction(points, firstPoint,
            indexFarthest, tolerance, ref pointIndexsToKeep);
            DouglasPeuckerReduction(points, indexFarthest,
            lastPoint, tolerance, ref pointIndexsToKeep);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The distance of a point from a line made from point1 and point2.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pt1">The PT1.</param>
    /// <param name="pt2">The PT2.</param>
    /// <param name="p">The p.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Double PerpendicularDistance
        (Point Point1, Point Point2, Point Point)
    {
        //Area = |(1/2)(x1y2 + x2y3 + x3y1 - x2y1 - x3y2 - x1y3)|   *Area of triangle
        //Base = v((x1-x2)²+(x1-x2)²)                               *Base of Triangle*
        //Area = .5*Base*H                                          *Solve for height
        //Height = Area/.5/Base

        Double area = Math.Abs(.5 * (Point1.X * Point2.Y + Point2.X *
        Point.Y + Point.X * Point1.Y - Point2.X * Point1.Y - Point.X *
        Point2.Y - Point1.X * Point.Y));
        Double bottom = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Point1.X - Point2.X, 2) +
        Math.Pow(Point1.Y - Point2.Y, 2));
        Double height = area / bottom * 2;

        return height;

        //Another option
        //Double A = Point.X - Point1.X;
        //Double B = Point.Y - Point1.Y;
        //Double C = Point2.X - Point1.X;
        //Double D = Point2.Y - Point1.Y;

        //Double dot = A * C + B * D;
        //Double len_sq = C * C + D * D;
        //Double param = dot / len_sq;

        //Double xx, yy;

        //if (param < 0)
        //{
        //    xx = Point1.X;
        //    yy = Point1.Y;
        //}
        //else if (param > 1)
        //{
        //    xx = Point2.X;
        //    yy = Point2.Y;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    xx = Point1.X + param * C;
        //    yy = Point1.Y + param * D;
        //}

        //Double d = DistanceBetweenOn2DPlane(Point, new Point(xx, yy));
    }

}
```