# Freehand image cropping with mouse and get all points in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, crop

I want to implement the freehand cropping on the image using the mouse in c# WinForms,

As there is rectangle cropping available but I need arbitrary/freehand selection of the image.

Actually, I need a cropped image in arbitrary/freehand form for further operations and then combine the cropped image with the original image.

I want to get all the coordinates and points of cropped image and also show crop image in other PictureBox. As I have to use the cropped image for ImageSteganography.

So, I need all the information about the cropped image part for future use. Here is [FreeHand Cropping Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ky8d.png)

Comment: [Edit points of FreeShape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50718793/7444103) -- [How to drag and move shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38749134/7444103) etc.

Comment: You need to: Collect the mousepoints into a graphicspath and create a region from it. now you can draw onto that region. done.